# Entity framework 6 IQueryable does not update with separate calls

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6, iqueryable

I have an unusual problem where by if I make separate calls to an IQueryable the initial call that creates the IQueryable will generate SQL specific to the first call. This can be seen when debugging and observing the internal query.

When I make inline calls such as:

```
IQueryable<TableEntity> tEnt = dbCtx.table.AsNoTracking().Include(t=> t.someRefData).Where(t => t.Id >= 10);
```

this produces the correct internal SQL query.

However If I dynamically make the query with separate distinct calls such as:

```
IQueryable<TableEntity> tEnt = dbCtx.table.AsNoTracking();
tEnt.Include(t=> t.someRefData);
tEnt.Where(t => t.Id >= 10);
```

The internal SQL query does not update beyond the declaration of tEnt to reflect these preceeding calls.

Have I total mis-understood how IQueryable works?

Comment: `Include` and `Where` return new `IQueryable` objects, you are discarding them.

Comment: Oh im so having a derp moment ofcourse they do. The calls dont apply to the calling object only create based on what was refered to it.

Comment: Btw. a IQueryable is a kind of concatenation of commands. Is used similar to IEnumerable, but the concated commands are not called until the IQueryable is converted into an object (.singe(); .first(); singleOrDefault(); .firstOrDefault()), into an array or into an IEnumerable (e.g. .ToList() ). befor that conversation it is just a command. Also: you have to make the call before you close your container, or you will get an exception, if you try to run your concatinated commands on a closed connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tEnt = tEnt.Include(t=> t.someRefData);
```